# Insert value into a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to figure out how to insert the same value into the entire column of a table? The table already exists and I have an empty column into which I would like to insert a certain value, for example, today's date. I have only found sources explaining how to insert values into an entire row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='newValue'
```

newValue can also be an expression.

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 7):

I think we need a bit more info to understand the issue, it sounds like you just want...

```
INSERT INTO table_foo (my_empty_column_name) values (current_date);
```

If you've already got data there and you want to UPDATE that column for all rows then...

```
UPDATE table_foo SET my_empty_column_name = current_date;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would think you're trying to UPDATE.

```
UPDATE myTable set myColumn = 'WHATEVER'
```